# If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then the inclusion is a quasi-isometry if and only if $H$ has finite index in $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometric-group-theory

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then the inclusion is a quasi-isometry if and only if $H$ has finite index in $G$.

I am reading through some notes on Geometric Group Theory and I came across this side fact in the discussion.  Any suggestions on how to solve it?

I know a map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a quasi-isometry iff it is a quasi-isometric embedding and a quasi-isometric inverse $g:Y\rightarrow X$ such that for all $y \in Y$ there exists $x \in X$ such that $d_X(g\circ f(x),y)< D$ and such that for all $x \in X$ there exists $y \in Y$ such that $d_Y(f\circ g(y),x)< D$.  Alternatively $g$ could just be an isometric embedding as well and the definitions coincide.

Comment: Are all your groups finitely-generated?

Comment: Yes they are f.g.

Comment: Which direction are you having problems with, the "if" or the "only if"?

Comment: Both.  Just started reading up on the subject so not sure what tools to use.

Comment: It should be clear that if the index is infinite then there are points of $G$ at arbitrarily large distance from $H$. Otherwise, if there was a bound $K$ on this distance, then the set of all words of length at most $K$ would include elements of all cosets of $H$ in $G$. If the index is finite, then a word of length $n$ in a generating set of $G$ can be rewritten as a word of length at most $n$ in the associated Schreier generators of $H$, which implies that the embedding is quasi-isometric.