# Quasi isometric embedding between two groups

Tags: isometry, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be the subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R)}$ generated by $ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and   $ \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Let $H$ is generated by  $ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

I want to prove that $H$ is not [quasi-isometric embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isometry) to $G$.

My attempt: Let $ a=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $b = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. Now I have found a relation $bab^{-1} = a^2$.

Now I cannot proceed further. Please help.

Comment: What can you already use? Is [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888274/if-h-is-a-subgroup-of-g-then-the-inclusion-is-a-quasi-isometry-if-and-only) useful?

Comment: Hint: Iterate the identity that you found.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: no, it is a different (but related) notion.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Iterate the identity means $b^n a b^{-n}  = a^{2n}$? Please advise.

Comment: Right. Now, compare the word lengths of LHS and RHS.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Can you advise about comparing word length of LHS and RHS more explicitly? I cannot understand.

Comment: Yes, count the number of letters.

Comment: Do you already know what the word metric is? Otherwise, you cannot solve such problems.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes. $d(g, h) = min\{n \mid \text{there exists } s_1, \cdots s_n \in S \cup S^{-1}, h = s_1 \cdots s_n g\}$.

Comment: How many letters are in $a^{2n}$ in terms of $n$?  How about $b^nab^{-n}$?  If you cannot count this, nobody can possibly help you.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Sorry, I got it. $a^{2n}$ has $2n$ letters and other has $2n+1$ letters. Please advise me.

Comment: @MoisheKohan How the number of letters leads the fact  that two groups are not quasi isometric?  Please advise me.

Comment: "$H$ is not quasi-isometric embedding to $G$" is incorrect English and should be "$H$ is not quasi-isometric embedded into $G$"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here it goes. The formula
$$
b a b^{-1}=a^2,
$$
and its consequence $b a^m b^{-1}=a^{2m}$,
applied inductively yield:
$$
b^n a b^{-n}=a^{(2^n)}, n\ge 0. 
$$
(This is where you have miscalculated. I will leave it to you to check the above formula using induction.)

For $w\in H$ let $|w|_H$ denote the distance of $w$ in $H$ to the neutral element in the group $H=\langle a\rangle$  with respect to the generating set $\{a^{\pm 1}\}$. Similarly, define $|u|_G$ for $u\in G$ with respect to $\{a^{\pm 1}, b^{\pm 1}\}$.

Then we get:
$$
|a^{2^n}|_H= 2^n, |a^{2^n}|_G\le 2n+1. 
$$
Since
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n+1}{2^n}=0,
$$
we conclude that there are no constants $K\ge 1, A\ge 0$ such that
$$
K^{-1} |w|_H - A\le |w|_G 
$$
for all elements $w\in H$. Hence, the inclusion map $H\to G$ is not a quasi-isometric embedding.